# loading xsl templates for node siblings using parameters

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a table that is calculated using many variables. During the calculation, i keep record of these calculations in a xml file.

The thing is I need to format this xml in different layouts

- one starting from the invoices
- the other starting from the column names.

Fore each 'invoice' there is a 'cost' specified which can be a part from the invoice's value and each 'cost' is being placed in a column from the table.

My XML is like this:

```
<table>
    <invoices>
        <invoice id="1" value="230" supplier="First supplier"/>
    </invoices>
    <costs>
        <cost id="1" invoice="1" column="2" value="100">
            <calculation>
                <tenant name="Tenant1" cost="30" />
                <tenant name="Tenant2" cost="70" />
            </calculation>
        </cost>
        <cost id="2" invoice="1" column="1" value="130">
            <calculation>
                <tenant name="Tenant1" cost="50" />
                <tenant name="Tenant2" cost="50" />
            </calculation>
            <calculation>
                <tenant name="Tenant1" cost="10" />
                <tenant name="Tenant2" cost="20" />
            </calculation>
        </cost>
    </costs>
    <columns>
        <column id="1" name="Column name 1"/> 
        <column id="2" name="Column name 2"/> 
    </columns>
</table>
```

So my expected output would be something like

```
Column name
    Costs from which invoice
        Calculations
```

Or

```
Invoice
    Spread over a column based on cost
        Calculations
```

My XSL looks something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="table/costs/cost">
                <xsl:call-template name="cost"></xsl:call-template>
                <h1>Mere</h1>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="cost" name="cost">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="invoice"></xsl:apply-templates>
        <h1>Cheltuiala <xsl:value-of select="@id"></xsl:value-of></h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <xsl:call-template name="invoice" >
                <xsl:with-param name="idInvoice" select="@invoice"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </li>
            <li>Si ceva avcolo</li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="invoice" match="table/invioces/invoice[@id=@idInvoice]">
        <xsl:param name="idInvoice"></xsl:param>
        <p>Found something</p>
        <h2><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></h2>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So what I want to do is call a template based on an attribute from a node, display the data and continue to the next node.

IS this possible?

Comment: You forgot to provide the exact wanted output from the transformation. Please, edit the question and provide this necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `current()` function to refer to the current context-node. But to do this, you need to select the nodes when calling the template or before:

```
<xsl:template name="cost">
    ...
    <xsl:for-each match="/table/invoices/invoice[@id=current()/@invoice]">
        <xsl:call-template name="invoice"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

- `@id` refers to the `id=` attribute of the selected `<invoice>`.
- `current()/@invoice` refers to the `invoice=` attribute of the context `<cost>`.

It is often easier to use `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:for-each>` + `<xsl:call-template>`, but you would have to rewrite the template to use `match=` instead of `name=`.

```
<xsl:template match="cost">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates match="/table/invoices/invoice[@id=current()/@invoice]"/>
    ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="invoice">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

If you need to use a tag-name multiple times, you can use modes:

```
<xsl:template match="cost">
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates match="/table/invoices/invoice[@id=current()/@invoice]"
                         mode="cost-invoice"/>
    ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="cost-invoice" match="invoice">
    ...
</xsl:template>
```